# ActionView:MissingTemplate Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview, spree

It has been more than 2 hours trying to find the solution of this error which is appearing in my development.log file

Can someone explain what is causing this error :

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template C:/Users/Sadan masroor/Desktop/New
 folder/aromapersona/public/404.html with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rh
tml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "C:/Users/Sad
an masroor/Desktop/New folder/aromapersona/app/views", "C:/Users/Sadan masroor/D
esktop/New folder/aromapersona/app/views", "C:/Users/Sadan masroor/Desktop/New f
older/aromapersona/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spree-0.60.1/app/views", "C:/Us
ers/Sadan masroor/Desktop/New folder/aromapersona/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
spree_sample-0.60.1/app/views", "C:/Users/Sadan masroor/Desktop/New folder/aroma
persona/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spree_promo-0.60.1/app/views", "C:/Users/S
adan masroor/Desktop/New folder/aromapersona/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spree
_dash-0.60.1/app/views", "C:/Users/Sadan masroor/Desktop/New folder/aromapersona
/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spree_api-0.60.1/app/views", "C:/Users/Sadan masr
oor/Desktop/New folder/aromapersona/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spree_auth-0.6
0.1/app/views", "C:/Users/Sadan masroor/Desktop/New folder/aromapersona/vendor/b
undle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.3.3/app/views", "C:/Users/Sadan masroor/Desktop/N
ew folder/aromapersona/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spree_core-0.60.1/app/views
", "C:/Users/Sadan masroor/Desktop/New folder/aromapersona", "C:/"):
```

Apparently everything is working well in the browser so I am under the impression that there is something wrong with the spree.Not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think it happening:

You have a 404 page somewhere that is being rendered or called in correctly, hence this error.  Perhaps you are missing :layout => false? Anyway, since it is a layout missing, rails renders a 404 anyway. Therefore, it seems to work in production since your 404 page is rendered, but in reality you are getting this error. Is it in your production logs too?

Comment: No it is not appearing in my production log. It is just appearing in my development log.